# How to crawl data coming from ajax with jquery?

Tags: jquery, .net, ajax

how can i crawl data of any page in which data is coming from ajax with jquery,i want to do it by C# console.

Comment: What do you mean by 'crawl data of a page'?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it depends on the structure you use to post your data.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "path.to.my.net.page",
    data: (my.data),
    error: function(xhr,status,error) {/* what to do if something is wrong */},
    success: function(return.data) {/* what to do if everything is all right */}
});
```

The previuos snippet is a classical AJAX call via jQuery. The "my.data" structure will be processed by "my.net.page". The data will be accessible as it was a normal post variable in your .NET code, but depending on the structure, it must be processed in different ways.

The data may be a simple comma separeted string (boooh), or a well formed JSON structure.
JSON lets you shape your data as a serialized object that you can deserialize and access in your csharp page. There are a lot of library. I suggest you [JSON.NET](http://json.codeplex.com/). Have a try [here](http://json2csharp.com/) with this sample:

```
{"id" : "0023", "name" : "Zap", items : [{"itemId" : "1", itemValue : "One"}, {"itemId": "2", "itemValue" : "Two"}]}
```